# iPhone - Combining a Tab Bar with multiple navigation bars

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to build an iPhone application that has a Tab bar as the root controller and several navigation bars. My doubt is, shall I create one NavigationBarController class for each navigation bar that I want to put in the application? Or is it possible to create only a single navigation controller that manages all the navigation bar controllers that exist in the application?

In the case that multiple navigation controllers exist in the application, can I use the "self" to access the correct navigation controller that pushes/pops the view? Or should I use the delegate of the Application delegate to access each navigation bar controllers?

(I am assuming that all navigation bar controllers are declared in the application delegate, is this approach correct or is there a more elegant approach?)

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to achieve this is to create a Tab Bar application and then change each item in the tab bar to be a UINavigationController.  If you do this, you can definitely use self to access the navigationController - specifically you can use `self.navigationController`.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for possible leak in this part of the above code:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
```

You could use this instead:

```
UIBarButtonItem* rightButtonBar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButtonBar;
[rightButtonBar release];
```

;) ... or use autorelease

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I will look into it! Miquel

Answer (score 0):

Insert a unique `UINavigationController` for each tab.

You can't have a single controller manage across multiple tabs, since a navigation controller can only have a single linear stack of view controllers.  Each tab should have it's own navigation controller with a different root controller in each one.

Answer (score 0):

> The common way to achieve this is to create a Tab Bar application and
>   then change each item in the tab bar to be a UINavigationController.

This is THE way of achieving this. I have loaded 5 navigation controllers into a tab bar controllor. The key tip is to plan the navigations of the App, as every navController should take place where a new navigation tree starts.